# How to classifier topics/partitions in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

For example user can subscribe on specific categories of films.

When a new films apperas in Kafka I must to send information about that to consumers who subscribes on category of film.

How to classifier this? Using partigion or topics? Because categories can be more over 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a topic `user-subscriptions` that holds at least the `userID` and the `categoryID`. For each subscription, make sure to create a different record even for the same user. For example,

```
{"subscriptionID": 1, "userID": 1, "categoryID": 100}
{"subscriptionID": 2, "userID": 1, "categoryID": 26}
...
```

---

Now make sure to partition this topic by `categoryID` so that the records for the same category are placed in the same partition.

Now once your application identifies a new film of a particular category, you just need to go through the records of the partition that holds all the subscriptions for that category and while consuming, notify the users for the new film using the `userID`.

Comment: Do you mean topic `user-subscriptions` and inside topic partitions with specific key `categoryID`. In this case partitions an be more 1000, as I know for Kafka it is not good from performance point, is not?

Comment: So. also about your second remark, should I create topic films, when film is added to this topic I must get category of film and get what next?

Comment: you just need to go through the records of the partition, do you mean  through which records?

Comment: @AliceMessis I wouldn’t say so. Partitioning is the ultimate way to achieve high(er) performance in Kafka (assuming your overall configuration and architecture make sense).

Comment: @AliceMessis Gi through the subscriptions for that category (i.e. the partition) in order to get all user ids which are subscribed to that category.

Comment: How to do that, using streams and put filterd data to users topic in partitin user_id?

Comment: @AliceMessis Kafka Streams or a simple Kafka consumer.

Comment: If to use Kafka streams, where to put filtered data (users_id)? Or I need add found films to another partition with key user_id?

Comment: @AliceMessis If you have one partition per category you don’t need to filter anything. Just consume all the messages in that partition.

Comment: Do you mean partition per category for films topic?  `Films.100 -> [0,1,2...]` ? or for user_subscriptions: `user_subscriptions.100 -> [0,1,2...]`

Comment: I can not get how to organize transmit data to subscribers that new film came using stream and where to store filtered data (films) after I get user_id

Comment: @AliceMessis Sorry but I am not sure I follow.